# How to run feature file scenarios through Test Explorer in Python VS Code?

Tags: python, gherkin, python-behave, test-explorer, pytest-bdd

I am trying to run my Behave scenarios in VS Code through test explorer.
My feature file and steps file are properly bind as the same project works on Pycharm Professional Edition (trail version). I do not see my test explorer loading my scenarios.What configurations do I need to set? I am new to python.
I have installed below extensions that supports behave.

1. Behave test explorer
2. Cucumber Gherkin full support
3. Specflow Tools
4. Test explorer UI
5. Python

Below is my launch.json

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "venv"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./Tests",
        "-p",
        "*test.py"
    ]
}
```

No tests in test explorer:
[image]